# Python regular expression with repeating subgroup

Tags: python, regex

```
s2="SELECT a,b,c FROM sch.Table1 a, Table4, (SELECT a, b, c FROM (select c,d FROM sch1.Table2 where x=1),Table3 where ....)"
s3="SELECT a,b,d,e FROM sch.Table1 a, sch.Table4 b, schb.Table3 WHERE 1=1"
s4="SELECT a,b,c FROM sch.table1 a,sch.table2 b WHERE colb=colc and col2=(SELECT colid FROM SCH2.TABLE3,SCH3.TABLE4 WHERE 1=1"
```

I have the SQL strings like the above. I'm trying to define a regular expression which would get all the Table's (sch.Table1, Table4, sch1.Table2,etc..) from the SQLs

I used the following and it returns only one table_name `['sch.Table2']`

```
w1 = re.findall(r"(?:SELECT\s+.+\s+FROM\s)(?:(\w*\.*\w+)\s*\w?,?)",s2,re.IGNORECASE)
print w1
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use a sql parser. regex is going to get you nowhere.

Comment: Works for me, with your code. I get `['sch1.Table2']`, `['sch.Table1']` and `['SCH2.TABLE3']`.

Comment: Thanks Simonzack for suggesting to use sqlparser. I used the script in the following URL with minor tweak to get the table names.
https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/blob/master/examples/extract_table_names.py
Thanks Adam,Kasra and Bhat for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `regex` you can use `split` in list comprehension :

```
>>> l=[s2,s3,s4]
>>> [i for s in l for i in s.split() if 'table' in i or 'Table' in i]
['sch.Table1', 'Table4,', 'sch1.Table2', 'x=1),Table3', 'sch.Table1', 'sch.Table4', 'schb.Table3', 'sch.table1', 'a,sch.table2']
```

or with `regex`:

```
>>> [re.findall(r'[\w\.]+Table\d|table\d',s) for s in l]
[['sch.Table1', 'sch1.Table2'], ['sch.Table1', 'sch.Table4', 'schb.Table3'], ['table1', 'table2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way:

```
>>> s2="SELECT a,b,c FROM sch.Table1 a, Table4, (SELECT a, b, c FROM (select c,d FROM sch1.Table2 where x=1),Table3 where ....)"
>>> s3="SELECT a,b,d,e FROM sch.Table1 a, sch.Table4 b, schb.Table3 WHERE 1=1"
>>> s4="SELECT a,b,c FROM sch.table1 a,sch.table2 b WHERE colb=colc and col2=(SELECT colid FROM SCH2.TABLE3,SCH3.TABLE4 WHERE 1=1"
>>> re.findall(r"[\w\.]*Table.?",s2,re.IGNORECASE)
['sch.Table1', 'Table4', 'sch1.Table2', 'Table3']
>>> re.findall(r"[\w\.]*Table.?",s3,re.IGNORECASE)
['sch.Table1', 'sch.Table4', 'schb.Table3']
>>> re.findall(r"[\w\.]*Table.?",s4,re.IGNORECASE)
['sch.table1', 'sch.table2', 'SCH2.TABLE3', 'SCH3.TABLE4']
```